# AngularJs App Cache Busting with Parameters or Alternate Better Method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, cookies

I have an issue where `Ctrl + F5`, and even a Chrome add-on for clearing a browser cache does not seem to do a complete job of clearing a browser's cache. I am not sure why.

These mentioned techniques clears and reloads most of the files, but it seems as if some stuff that has been added to $sessionStorage or cookies still lingers. Which is strange, as $sessionStorage should be cleared when you press `Ctrl + F5` (according to my understanding), not too sure about the cookies though?

Anyway, I came across the approach of **cache-busting**, and this seems to be a great and simple method for forcing a cache clear with a new version release.

Example: Adding and updating a version parameter to a style sheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css?v=2.1.2">
```

**My question is:** Do I have to add this parameter to each and every `.css` and `.js` file listed in my `index.html` (there are at least 75)?

**If so, is there an "easier" or better way to do this?**

Taking into account `application cache` has been deprecate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

And Service Workers are still seen as being in the experimental stage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers